# Show Window specific JumpList in Windows

Tags: winapi, jump-list, shell32

My program opens multiple windows on taskbar (not MDI). I want to display a Jumplist that is specific for each Window. How is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows uses the [Application User Model ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378459(v=VS.85).aspx) to group taskbar buttons and jump lists. This lets you group multiple processes together, or in your case split multiple windows from the same process.

You can assign a different AppUserModelID to a window by using the [`SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378430(v=vs.85).aspx) function to obtain the window's [`IPropertyStore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761474(v=vs.85).aspx) interface and then set its [`System.AppUserModel.ID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391569(v=vs.85).aspx) property.